# Comparing JPasswordfield and JTextField In IF Statement keeps going to else statement

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

I'm working on a login system program on Java.

Every time I write down the user and password and press Login it always goes towards the else statement. I did turn the `passwordfield` into a string but it still doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panelC(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panelN(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //frame.add(panelW(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    //frame.add(panelE(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(panelS(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}

public static JPanel panelC()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel("Username");
    label2 = new JLabel("Password");
    field1 = new JTextField(10);
    pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(field1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(pass);
    return panel;
}
public static JPanel panelN()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,25));
    return panel;
}
public static JPanel panelS()
{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,5));
    button1 = new JButton("Login");
    JLabel test = new JLabel();
    JLabel test2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel test3 = new JLabel();
    JLabel test4 = new JLabel();
    panel.add(test);
    panel.add(test2);
    panel.add(test3);
    panel.add(test4);
    panel.add(button1);
    char[] p = pass.getPassword();
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
        {
            try
            {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("Logins.txt"));
                String user = scan.nextLine();
                String pass = scan.nextLine();
                String inPass = new String(p);
                String inUser = field1.getText();
                while (scan.hasNextLine())
                {

                    if (inUser.equals(user) && inPass.equals(pass))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Granted");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user = scan.nextLine();
                        pass = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    return panel;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `getText()` in code where you create a component, so this is being called before a user has had any chance of entering anything into the text field. Instead this method should only be called from within an appropriate listener, such as an ActionListener that is triggered by the user pressing an accept JButton or by pressing enter in a JTextField.

Solution: fill your inPass and inUser Strings within the ActionListener, not within the creational code.

Other problems:

1. You're grossly over-using static, suggesting that your code needs to be refactored so that statics (other than the main method) aren't needed.
2. In general it's not a good idea to create a String out of your password char[] array, but rather to compare char arrays. This makes your password more secure, although this is not such a big deal in a simple academic exercise such as this one. Still you should know this.
3. Same for storing password text in a text file -- not very secure (as you can imagine).
4. Most Swing login windows should be modal JDialogs and not JFrames as they present information that absolutely must be dealt with before the program progresses, and a modal dialog will halt program flow until it is no longer visible.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my poor coding, I'm still in the learning process in Java. I'm improving of what I can do and hope it works ahah. If reading your comment right, your telling me that i should put InPass and InUser into the Actionlistener, Yes I did this before but when I compile it, it still goes towards the else statement :(.

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite new but when I try paste in the code its too long, is there a better way?

Comment: @DannyNguyen: nope. Add text that explains the code, and the site will allow it. Don't post nonsense, but rather information that helps us to understand the problem and the code.

Comment: Well I didn't know what to do so I just updated my code if that is alright?

Comment: @DannyNguyen: now if your code isn't working you need to do some debugging. Print the Strings obtained within the actionperformed method...

Comment: I did do some Investigating, I'm not sure if this would help but I put a "test" string in my else statement and it prints out "test" string 3 times and have reach the end of my txt file.

Comment: @DannyNguyen: I would either run through a debugger, checking field values within the action listener, or else would use println statements within the while loop to print all the Strings obtained within the action listener's while loop, as well as the result of the boolean check.

Comment: if you meant by testing all my statements in the while loop with a string to see if it responds I have. The only thing that is not responding is my If Statement. Sorry if I'm wasting your time by the way - also ran through a debugger came out clean